# Is there a map between options for linux ld linker and options for MSVS link.exe

Tags: visual-c++, linker, mingw, ld, msys

Can someone point me to a map for converting a set of linux ld options to the corresponding set of options for MSVS link.exe?

link.exe seems to think I want to load /DEBUG.

This is a mess for me since I am trying to use clang for MSVCC 10.0 to build c99-to-c89 in MingW/MSYS which means I have to use the MS linker, not the "linux" one in MSYS.

Comment: `ld` must have more than a hundred options. You'd probably be better off asking about the specific options you're trying to use.

Comment: link.exe only takes about 50 options, so it'd need to start from that end, not the ld end.  Anyway, specifically, -l and -g.  -g should be /DEBUG but for whatever reason link wants to load \some-default-path\DEGUG.OBJ.  Maybe I just need to know where debug.obj is located?

Comment: Maybe it'll help if you can show the link command you're using and the exact error message(s).

Comment: As it turns out, I was trying to make the c99-to-c89 package which comes with a Makefile and a Makefile.w32.  Using the right make file did me a lot of good!  Thanks for the help.